# Using a Scanner for keywords with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner

I'm Trying to use a scanner to scan for a set of words as you can see below, however I'm attempting to use this scanner and It's completely freezing my program I think I'm way off, need some advice.

```
            frames.get(frameNo-1).colors.add(currentColor);             
                            break;

        case "LINE":        currentShape = new Line2D.Double(Integer.parseInt(a[1]),Integer.parseInt(a[2]),Integer.parseInt(a[3]),Integer.parseInt(a[4]));
                            frames.get(frameNo-1).shapes.add(currentShape);
                            frames.get(frameNo-1).colors.add(currentColor);             
                            break;

        default: System.out.println("Input Instruction Not Recognized");    
    }
} 

catch (RuntimeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Invalid input instruction on line " + lineNo);
}
```

Comment: `String fileName = scan.next();`. What is provided to the scanner?

Comment: You first close `scan` and then try to invoke its `nextLine()` method, that cannot work

Comment: I'm wanting to provide the scanner the file which I have selected with Jfilechooser, I've removed the close scan and it's still not working.

Comment: It’s good to pare down your code to the relevant parts, but you went too far.  Your question is about a Scanner and a JFileChooser, but the code in your question now contains neither of these.  This significantly reduces the usefulness of the given answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
String fileName = scan.next();
```

You are trying to use a Scanner to get some data from the keyboard.

But then you display a `JFileChooser` to have the user select a file.

Then you try to read data from the `Scanner`.

Well unless you type something at the keyboard the Scanner will just sit there and wait (so get rid of that statement).

If you want to use the Scanner to read the file selected in the chooser then you actually need to get the filename that was selected. Something like:

```
File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
```

Then you can use the `File` with the `Scanner`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( file );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more information and working examples on how to get the file name.

Comment: I've tried adjusting it and I'm having no luck, I'm not the best at java by any means I've tried changing some things which you have suggested but I'm still having problems.

Comment: @Adam, `I'm still having problems.` - well I have no idea what you problems might be since I am not a mind reader.Break the problem down into steps. 1). Create a simple program that displays a JFileChooser and allows the user to select a file. You can then use System.out.println(...) to display the file choosen. 2) Next you create a program that reads a file when you hardcode a filename using the Scanner. 3) You combine knowledge from programs 1 and 2 to dynamically choose the file name using the file chooser. If you have a problem with any step then post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing an event driven programming paradigm, a Swing GUI, with a linear console programming paradigm, and the two don't mix well nor should they mix. The technical reason for your program freezing is that your use of Scanner is blocking the Swing event thread, and so it cannot perform its essential functions of drawing the GUI and interacting with the user.

The solution is simple: Choose one or the other, console or Swing GUI and stick with it.

Note that it's OK to have the Scanner scan the *file*, that's a completely different use of it, but it's not OK to have it work with the `System.in`, unless in very specific situations, such as when working with secondary processes, and in this situation you'd do work with the Scanner in a background thread.

Other issues:

- Naming confusion: you're giving classes, e.g., Frame and Component, names that are already part of the standard Java GUI library, and this can confuse us, your instructors, and even yourself. You want to avoid doing this -- use more original class names if possible.
- Code formatting: some of your code is all left justified making it hard to read and debug.
- Window swapping: you appear to be swapping GUI windows, a GUI design that will often fatigue the user. Better usually to swap JPanel views via CardLayout.